# телеграм бот не откликается на выхож юзеров types.ContentTypes.LEFT_CHAT_MEMBER

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.LEFT_CHAT_MEMBER)
async def left_member(message: types.Message):
    print(message.chat.type)
    if (message.chat.type == 'group' or message.chat.type == 'supergroup'):
        await message.delete()
        user = message.left_chat_member
        full_name = user.full_name
        user_id = user.id
        print(f"Участник покинул чат: {full_name} (ID: {user_id})")
```

Потребовалось добавить в бот реакцию на выход юзера, не откликается,
aiogram~=2.25.2,
в чате 2500 человек
message.chat.type пишет что 'supergroup'.

Попробовал уже все.

Случайно выяснилось, что при добавлении бота в чат он прекрасно реагирует на событие входа и выхода.

Comment: Интересно, зачем скобки в условии if? Это же не хаваскрипт.

Comment: содержательный ответ...

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий, между прочим.